# How to test delayed functionality of a system?

Tags: php, testing, automated-tests

Let's say i have a frontend which is communicating with a webshop API. One action is to place an order. In the end, this order gets processed and shipped to a queueing system.
Since this is no synchronous process, how is it possible to send something to the API but "wait" for the result on the queue side and compare that with the expected result? This could take up to 3 minutes ... what are usually some tools/approaches for that? Postman is good for API tests but is it also possible to connect to the queue system and check the results? What about phpunit? is it capable?

The goal is to test that stuff completely automatically in the end

Best

Answer (score 0):

Testing for asynchronous behavior is no problem as long as there is visible side effect. If I understood correctly, your goal is to sense whether the order has been submitted to the queue.

When it comes to automated tests, the only difference is that you can not assert right away. You have to wait or fail if it takes too long.

[This little assertion library](https://github.com/matthiasnoback/phpunit-asynchronicity) is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: I want to check if its and what is on the queue. Processing such an order will take time since there are also task runner which are processing the order internally. Finally they must be exported to the queue and thats exactly the thing i want to test. What kind/category of this is this? Is this also an API test? Or functional test?

Comment: I'd categorize this as a functional test.

Comment: So, let me check the library. Sounds exactly as what i need. Thanks so far.